# Using IoU localization loss in OD API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

Several papers, like [this one](https://giou.stanford.edu/GIoU.pdf) for example, claim that IoU localization loss yields better performance than the standard smooth L1 loss.

When trying to use IoU localization loss, i.e. use this line in the config file:

```
...
localization_loss {
   weighted_iou {
   }
}
...
```

I always get `found NaN in loss` error. If I add a small consant (e.g. `1e-7`) to the denominator in `matched_iou` like so:

```
def matched_iou(boxlist1, boxlist2, scope=None):
  """Compute intersection-over-union between corresponding boxes in boxlists.

  Args:
    boxlist1: BoxList holding N boxes
    boxlist2: BoxList holding N boxes
    scope: name scope.

  Returns:
    a tensor with shape [N] representing pairwise iou scores.
  """
  with tf.name_scope(scope, 'MatchedIOU'):
    intersections = matched_intersection(boxlist1, boxlist2)
    areas1 = area(boxlist1)
    areas2 = area(boxlist2)
    unions = areas1 + areas2 - intersections
    eps = 1e-7  # <- this is the small constant
    return tf.where(
        tf.equal(intersections, 0.0),
        tf.zeros_like(intersections), tf.truediv(intersections, unions + eps))
```

The `NaN` error is gone but loss values are really high and the training doesn't converge.

I'll appreciate any hint on this phenomenon.

Comment: How did you get to run the IOU loss function in the first place? When I change it to use IOU loss it raises an error about the shapes

Comment: Nevermind, you just need to reshape to batch sizes..

Comment: Hi @BrunoLerner, please share your updates about this issue, I still don't have a solution for that

Comment: I ran the experiment yesterday, and it also didn't converge..
So I was thinking during the night, did you reshape it to [batch_size, -1] or [batch_size, num_anchors, -1] ?
I have 2 hypotesis.. First is that I reshaped it wrongly, and the second one is that the prediction doesn't come in the way the boxlist constructor expects (which is [y_max, x_max, y_min, x_min])

Comment: Which model are you using? I am using SSD, and Im strongly suspecting that the problem is that the prediction tensor come in a shape that is very different from what matched_iou expects. Cause if you read some papers, the notation of the bounding box are relative to the anchor boxes

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of code digging, It seems that the `prediction_tensor` and `target_tensor` come to the IOU Loss function as encoded tensor (relative to the anchor boxes).
So the IoU function runs on non-sense values, cause it expects it in a decoded format.. There is a function to decode it under `BoxCoder` which depends on the coder you are using, but the problem is that to use that you need the `anchor boxes`.. and to get the anchor boxes inside the loss function it's not that easy.